# how to execute a task after varying time

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Class A 
{
 long x;
 method1()
  {
   x = current time in millisecs;
  }
 task()//want to run this after (x+30) time
}
```

I need to run task() after  (x+30) . x could be varying. if method1 is called, then task is scheduled to run after 30 from current time, but within that 30 timeperiod if method1 is called again then i want to cancel the previous task call and want to schedule a new call to task after 30 sec from current time. How should i create a scheduler or task of this type?

Went through the scheduledthreadpoolexecutor API but didn't find a scheduler of this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking 2 questions:

*1. How can I schedule a task with an arbitrary delay?*

You can use one of the [schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule%28java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) on a [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

```
int delay = System.currentTimeMillis + 30;
myScheduledExecutor.schedule(myTask, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

*2. How can I cancel an already running task?*

You cancel a task by calling [cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future) that is returned from the `schedule` method you called.

```
if (!future.isDone()){
    future.cancel(true);
}
future = myScheduledExecutor.schedule(myTask, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would record the time method1 is called and I would check every second whether the method was called 30 seconds ago. This way it will only perform the task when there has been no call for 30 seconds.

Comment: is this the only way of doing this like checking every second? and wouldn't that be an overhead if for approx every second there is thread switching

Comment: A CPU can context switch 10000 times per second. Checking every second isn't that much. You can create a Future which you cancel every time method1() is called.  This has the problem that the overhead is proportional to the number of times method1() is called. See serg10's example.  By polling, the cost is fixed and if it ok when you start doing this you know it will never get any worse. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Timer` and pass a callback into the `TimerTask` to schedule the next run. TimerTask can be cancelled with `cancel` method if needed. e.g.

```
package test;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTaskDemo {
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private MyTimerTask nextTask = null;

    private interface Callback {
        public void scheduleNext(long delay);
    }

    Callback callback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void scheduleNext(long delay) {
            nextTask = new MyTimerTask(this);
            timer.schedule(nextTask, delay);
        }
    };

    public static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        Callback callback;

        public MyTimerTask(Callback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // You task code
            int delay = 1000;
            callback.scheduleNext(delay);
        };
    }

    public void start() {
        nextTask = new MyTimerTask(callback);
        timer.schedule(nextTask, 1000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerTaskDemo().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: damn, it has been 6 years but this solution is the best!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you model your requirement using the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class of the JDK. Based on your requirements you will be scheduling the task in the timer as required.

Comment: Have a periodic task which checks whether a certain variables is set (meaning method1 was called) and based on that you will either re-schedule task() to be executed or you will cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do what you need is the following. Class `B` is the calling class.

```
class A {

    public void runAfterDelay(long timeToWait) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(timeToWait);

        task();
    }
}

class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new A();
        // run after 30 seconds
        a.runAfterDelay(30000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Class A 
{
 $x;
 function method1()
  {
   $time = microtime(true);
  }
 sleep($time + 30);
 task()//want to run this after (x+30) time
}
```

Comment: WTF is this? Not Java, that's for sure. -1

Comment: oh i thought this was tagged php